# When clicking a file in the editor browser the cursor is not moved in the file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to enable this behaviour (with plugins), I google searched and got nothing.

If it's not clear from the title, the problem I'm having is that lets say you want to delete the whole file contents, or format the file, you click once on the file in the editor browser, and have to click again in the file since the file is still selected in the editor browser instead of being inside the file contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If instead of clicking with the mouse, you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the file, it will open the file with focus inside the file.  You can navigate the explorer tree with the <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys.